# How do I remove a numerical data plot on a bar that I added in a line chart?

Tags: highcharts

[image]

This is the screenshot of what I am struggling with. I cannot figure out a way to remove the data label of "2800" on the bar chart that I added onto the graph. I have tried playing with the advanced and custom settings yet still could not figure out a way.

Answer (score 0):

In case of issues with using the `Everviz` platform please contact their support channel: support@everviz.com.